# duplicate page content after ajax to the same page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have simple registration formulae and I want I want to firstly send with ajax and without refreshing the page to control if I insert correct data and then just redirect to some other page. The problem is that after I send it through ajax to the same page everything is working but content of my page is being duplicate, I can see it twice...

here is my ajax

```
function registruj () {
    var name = $('#meno').val();
    var priez = $('#priezvisko').val();
    var log  = $('#login').val();
    var mail  = $('#mail').val();
    var cisloTel  = $('#cislo').val();
    var heslo = $('#heslo').val();
    var heslo1 = $('#heslo1').val();

    $.post( "", {
            'meno': name,
            'priezvisko': priez,
            'login':log,
            'mail':mail,
            'cislo':cisloTel,
            'heslo':heslo,
            'heslo1':heslo1,

        }, function (data) {
            $('#result').html(data);

        }


    );

    $('#nove').load(document.URL + ' #nove');

}
```

and this is my php file

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_POST["meno"]) ) {
    echo "kokot";
    echo $_POST['meno'];
    require "pripojenie.php";
    $meno = $_POST["meno"];
    $priezvisko = $_POST["priezvisko"];
    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $heslo = $_POST["heslo"];
    $hesloZnovu = $_POST["heslo1"];
    if(isset($_POST["pohlavie"]))
        $pohlavie = $_POST["pohlavie"];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $cislo = $_POST['cislo'];
    //$id = $_SESSION['id'];



}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>blblblbl</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script>$(function(){$('.img').fancybox();});</script>

    <style type="text/css"> </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="mojskript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
</head>
<body  class="registracia">
<div class="container">

<div id="nove">










        <form  >

            <table >
                <tr><td><label for="napdis">Vyplňte nasledujúci formulár:</label></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="radio" name="pohlavie" value="zena" id="zena" >Žena</td></tr>
                <br>
                <tr><td><input type="radio" name="pohlavie" value="muz" id="muz">Muž</td></tr>
                <br>
                <tr><td><label for="meno">Meno :</label></td><td><input type = "text" id="meno" name="meno"></td></tr><br>
                <tr><td><label for="priezvisko">Priezvisko :</label></td><td><input type = "text" id="priezvisko" name="priezvisko"></td></tr><br>
                <tr><td><label for="login">Login :</label></td>
                    <td><input type = "text" id="login" name="login"></td></tr><br>

                <?php
                if(isset($heslo)) {
                    if (($heslo != "" && $hesloZnovu != "") && ($heslo == $hesloZnovu)) {

                        $hesloOk = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<tr><td><label for="heslo">Heslo :</label><td><input type = "password" name="heslo"></td><td><label for="zleHeslo">Heslá sa nezhodujú</label></td></tr>';
                        $pocet = 1;
                    }
                }

                ?>
                <?php

                if(!isset($pocet)) {

                    echo'<tr ><td ><label for="heslo" > Heslo :</label ></td >
                    <td ><input type = "password"  id="heslo" name = "heslo" ></td ></tr ><br >';
                }
                ?>
                <tr><td><label for="heslo2">Heslo znovu :</label></td>
                    <td><input type = "password"  id="heslo1" name="heslo1"></td></tr><br>
                <?php
                if(isset($mail)) {
                    if (!stristr($mail, "@") OR !stristr($mail, ".")) {
                        echo '<tr><td><label for="email">E-mail :</label></td>
                        <td><input type = "text"  name="email"></td><td><label for="zlyMail">Zlý formát emailu</label></td></rd></tr><br>';
                    } else {
                        $mailOk = 1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo '<tr><td><label for="email">E-mail :</label></td>
            <td><input type = "text" id="mail" name="email"></td></tr><br>';

                }

                ?>

                <tr><td><label for="cislo">Telefónne číslo :</label></td>
                    <td><input type = "text" id="cislo" name="cislo"></td></tr><br>
                <tr><td><input type="button" value="Zaregistrovať" onclick="registruj()" ></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>

        <?php
        if(isset($mailOk) && isset($hesloOk)) {
            $length = 20;

            $randomString = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length);


            $zasifrovane = crypt($heslo,$randomString);
            echo $zasifrovane;
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO uzivatelia (Meno,Priezvisko,Login,Heslo,mail,pohlavie,cislo) VALUES ('$meno','$priezvisko','$login','$zasifrovane','$mail','$pohlavie','$cislo')");
            header("location:index.php");
        }
        ?>

    </div>

        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

How should I do that ?

Comment: Looks correct. What does document.URL contain at the time? If it already contains ....#nove then you will load #nove#nove

Comment: yes it´s allerady containt nove it´s div inside which is the part of page which I want to refresh with ajax or you meant something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `exit();` like :

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["meno"]) ) {
    echo "kokot";
    echo $_POST['meno'];
    require "pripojenie.php";
    $meno = $_POST["meno"];
    $priezvisko = $_POST["priezvisko"];
    $login = $_POST["login"];
    $heslo = $_POST["heslo"];
    $hesloZnovu = $_POST["heslo1"];
    if(isset($_POST["pohlavie"]))
        $pohlavie = $_POST["pohlavie"];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $cislo = $_POST['cislo'];
    //$id = $_SESSION['id'];
    exit();
}
```

Use `exit();` or `die();` when ajax processing done otherwise it will return all page content.

Comment: the exit is working but the exit stop document right after that part of php but I need whole page and whole code to be in process because later on according to what I sent in POST there are changes like displaying message wrong password or bad email format..

Comment: Okay, Then you can use separate ajax request handling file. That will only process your ajax request and return only required data.

Comment: and How I can do that ? :D you mean that send the ajax post to different php and then for example store the results in SESSIONS ?

Comment: Most probably but you don't need to use `$_SESSION` you can return data in `JSON`  format and process that data when Ajax request successfully Done.

Comment: Well since I am not much skilled in this whole ajax thing I used that trick with SESSION, thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 0):

Change success function to:

```
function (data) {
        $('#result').empty().html(data);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but it still being duplicated :(

Comment: why do you write this line $('#nove').load(document.URL + ' #nove')?comment it.

Comment: it´s some stuff I found on the internet for refreshing only part of page after ajax because I needed to reload some parts of page to see changes acording to my database, but you right I just figure it out that this times I don´t need it